# How to check if any value of a list or vector is contained in a data frame?

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame with some full names and a vector with first names:

```
d <- data.frame(myName = c("Adam Smith","John Smith","John Clarks "))

first <- c("Adam","Mark","Jim")
```

I need to check if any value from "first" is contained in each row from "d", so the result should look like this:

```
Adam Smith  TRUE
John Smith  FALSE
John Clarks FALSE
```

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Try: `grepl(paste0(first, collapse ="|"), d[,1])`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grepl()`:

```
d <- data.frame(full_names = c("Adam Smith","John Smith","John Clarks "))

first <- c("Adam","Mark","Jim")

d$check <- grepl(paste0(first, collapse = "|"), d$full_names)

d
    full_names check
1   Adam Smith  TRUE
2   John Smith FALSE
3 John Clarks  FALSE
```